# Collapse multiple lines into one lines and apply changes to each item in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to create an ArrayList of all Java keywords.

I copied and pasted them from a website I found, but they're all listed vertically. Is there any way to quickly collapse them all onto one line?

Also, I'd like to put each in quotations to denote that they are Strings. Is there a way to do that?

For illustrative purposes, this is what I've got in Eclipse:

```
public static ArrayList<String> keywords = {
        abstract
        assert
        boolean
        break
        byte
        case
        catch
        char
        class
        const
        continue
        default
        do
        double
        else
        enum
        extends
        final
        finally
        float
        for
        goto
        if
        implements
        import
        instanceof
        int
        interface
        long
        native
        new
        package
        private
        protected
        public
        return
        short
        static
        strictfp
        super
        switch
        synchronized
        this
        throw
        throws
        transient
        try
        void
        volatile
        while
```

**APPENDIX** Actually copying them into this very text field (without applying code formatting) collapses them into one line. However, I still need to put them all in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave them on separate lines. That makes the code more redable and doesn't force to scroll horizontally.

Use your IDE find-replace tool with regexps to introduce the quotes. Something like replace `([a-z]+)` with `"\1",` (in Eclipse) or `"$1",` (in IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Nah it's too much of a waste of space and I don't need them to be readable since I pretty much know what they all are and they don't change. I'd rather save the vertical space